# Partially transparent object from Blender loses texture's clarity in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, transparency, blender

I've got a texture which is transparent in most part.
I have it on the inside of the sphere.
When I create desired object in Blender, everything seems to work as intended.

However, when exporting .fbx file from Blender to Unity the texture is partially transparent.

I've also tried exporting in .obj but the transparency doesn't work there at all.

Do you have any idea on how to make the texture fully clear in Unity?

[image: UnityBadClarityTexture]

[image: BlenderGoodClarityTexture]

[image: BlenderTransparencyOptions]

Comment: The thing is I don't use any code in this part, it's just Blender -> Unity export.

Comment: I feel blind.  I dont see anything in the blender texture picture that is clear that isnt in the unity one.

Comment: In blender it's not transparent, but in Unity it's partially transparent (you can see the scene lines through it).

Comment: Ah - thats not how I read your statement

Comment: Got it, edited, so it's more clear. Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

I had to export the .blend file to Unity assets and then change the shader of object to "Sprites/Default".